# If statement with multiple || conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looping through an array of objects and trying to see if there is a better way to write this (i feel like there is).

This is my function below.

```
  getCallInfo = (callSch: any, security: any) => {
    const callObj = {
      CallTimingType: 'Not Callable',
      isCheckMark: null,
    };

    if (!security.IsCallable) return callObj;

    callSch.Calls.forEach((el: { CallTimingType: string }) => {
      if (el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.SpecificDates) {
        callObj.CallTimingType = 'Discrete';
        callObj.isCheckMark = true;
      }
      if (
        el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.AnyTime ||
        el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.Monthly ||
        el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates ||
        el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentDate
      ) {
        callObj.CallTimingType = 'Continuous';
        callObj.isCheckMark = true;
      }
    });

    return callObj;
  };
```

basically what is doing is returning the default object if security.IsCallable is false but if true looping through the array of objects and setting the default object to different values.   What I am basically doing is trying to refactor this.  `CallTimingType` is an object with these enum values.   Any thoughts?

Comment: You can create an array like `const continuousTypes = [CallTimingType.AnyTime, CallTimingType.Monthly, ...];` then use `if (continuousTypes.includes(el.CallTimingType))`

Comment: `[CallTimingType.AnyTime, CallTimingType.Monthly, CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates, CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentDate].includes(el.CallTimingType)` what about something like this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yea, I thought about that as well was just curious if there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate and test if `el.CallTimingType` matches any value.

```
if (
  el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.AnyTime ||
  el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.Monthly ||
  el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates ||
  el.CallTimingType === CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentDate
)
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
const callTimingTypes = [
     CallTimingType.AnyTime,
     CallTimingType.Monthly,
     CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates,
     CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentDate
];

if (callTimingTypes.some((t) => el.CallTimingType === t))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your clause with `switch case` operator to make it clear:

```js
callSch.Calls.forEach((el: { CallTimingType: string }) => {
  switch (el.CallTimingType) {
    case CallTimingType.SpecificDates:
      callObj.CallTimingType = 'Discrete';
      callObj.isCheckMark = true;
      break;
    case CallTimingType.AnyTime:
    case CallTimingType.Monthly:
    case CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates:
    case CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentD:
      callObj.CallTimingType = 'Continuous';
      callObj.isCheckMark = true;
      break;
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `Set`:

```js
callSch.Calls.forEach((el: { CallTimingType: string }) => {
  const discreteSet = new Set([CallTimingType.SpecificDates]);
  const continuousSet = new Set([
    CallTimingType.AnyTime,
    CallTimingType.Monthly,
    CallTimingType.OnPaymentDates,
    CallTimingType.AnyInterestAdjustmentD,
  ]);

  if (discreteSet.has(el.CallTimingType)) {
    callObj.CallTimingType = 'Discrete';
    callObj.isCheckMark = true;
  } else if (continuousSet.has(el.CallTimingType)) {
    callObj.CallTimingType = 'Continuous';
    callObj.isCheckMark = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer wit the `set` alternative